# реализация функции drag&drop для input type="file"

Tags: javascript

как реализовать функцию drag&drop в данной форме, нужно что б у пользователя был выбор либо перетащить файл в поле dropZone, либо если браузер такую функцию не поддерживает, то инпутом добавлять файл.

```js
$('#form-edit-product').on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById("form-edit-product"));
  formdata.append("action", "shop_data");
  formdata.append("do", "modify");
  formdata.append("subject", "merchandise");
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", "/api/", true);
  req.send(formdata);
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {}
});
```

```html
<form id="form-edit-product" name="form-edit-product">
  <h2>edit a Product</h2>

  <label>Upload image:
    <div id="dropZone">
      drag & drop
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="img">
  </label>

  <label>
    Name:
    <input name="name" type="text">
  </label>

  <label>
    ID:
    <input type="text" name="extern_id">
  </label>

  <label>
    Value:
    <input name="bonus_cost" type="text">
  </label>

  <label>
    Description:
    <textarea name="description"></textarea>
  </label>

  <input type="submit" value="SAVE">
</form>
```

[image: это внешний вид формы]

Comment: Возможно такое http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627350/17974 решение вам подойдёт.

Answer (score 3):

Осмелюсь предложить к ознакомлению (и использованию, если подойдет) вариант моего обработчика drag&drop полей для загрузки изображений. Я использую его уже несколько лет в самых различных проектах. За это время код сильно усложнился и оброс разнообразными фичами. Здесь я представлю "устаревшую" для меня, но более простую и избавленную от лишнего функционала версию. При желании, ее можно допилить и до красивой мультизагрузки файлов и до фильтрации выбора файлов по mime-type и вообще до всего, чего душа пожелает.

Да, я знаю, что существует масса плагинов подобной тематики. И я использовал штук несколько из них. Но очень быстро наступает такая ситуация, что тебе требуется нестандартное поведение от формы загрузки и приходится часами искать костыли для прикручивания нового функционала. Даже кастомизация стилей может оказаться проблемой, не говоря уже о том, чтобы выводить уже загруженные файлы в форме при загрузке страницы (к примеру, на редактировании существующего материала с картинками).

Основные **достоинства** предлагаемого метода:

- показ превью изображения (или полного изображения) сразу после выбора файла, до отправки формы. В том числе, можно добавлять функционал постобработки изображений, удаления добавленных файлов и т.д.
- возможность обработки и валидации файла уже на этапе заполнения формы. Файл отправляется на сервер сразу после выбора, что позволяет проверить его тип, размер, ширину и высоту (для изображений) и т.д.

Тем не менее, предлагаемый принцип загрузки, полагаю, **подойдет не всем**, так как:

- после перетаскивания файла в поле (или выбора через стандартное окошко) файл сразу же отправляется на сервер, где предполагается его обработка и сохранение. То есть не вместе с отправкой формы, как обычно, а сразу, после выбора файла.
- drop-зона представляет собой элемент `form`, что накладывает некоторые ограничения. К примеру, вы не можете разместить эту форму внутри другой формы. Придется либо выносить эту dropzone-форму за пределы основной, либо основную форму переделать на div и производить сбор данных из всех полей и отправку основной формы вручную (я поступаю, чаще всего, именно так. Люблю все делать самостоятельно)).

Теперь подробнее **о работе**:

- drop-зона, как уже было упомянуто, представляет собой элемент form с единственным input[type=file]. Стили маскируют этот инпут и мы видим приветливый квадратик, в который можно добавить надпись "перетащите сюда или кликните...".
- выбор файла осуществляется перетаскиванием на поле либо кликом на него и использованием стандартного окна выбора файла.
- после выбора файла, он сразу отправляется на сервер по адресу, указанному в аттрибуте action формы.
- в ответе сервера ожидается информация о загруженном файле и (по желанию) его превьюшке для отображения в форме. Имя файла сохраняется в скрытом поле рядом с формой (при желании, можно, конечно же, писать его в любой инпут или еще куда вздумается).
- после ответа сервера выдается либо сообщение об ошибке, либо (при успешном ответе) в форму добавляется превьюшка изображения и в скрытый input рядом с формой - имя файла.

**Что нужно доделать** в представленном коде, **чтобы запустить** у себя:

**1**. в аттрибуте action формы указан адрес, куда будет отправлен файл. Оттуда ожидается корректный ответ в формате json.

Это либо

```
{"error":"описание ошибки"}
```

в случае проблемы с файлом, либо

```
{
    "id": "id или имя файла. будет добавлен в основную форму в поле name=uploaded_image", //обязательно
    "thumbnail": "адрес превьюшки", //необязательно
    "filepath": "адрес основного файла", //обязательно, если не указан thumbnail
    "width": "ширина выводимого превью", //необязательно, можно указать в стилях или определить в параметрах myLoadImage, но пригодится в случае динамического размера изображений
    "height": "высота выводимого превью", //необязательно, можно указать в стилях или определить в параметрах myLoadImage, но пригодится в случае динамического размера изображений
}
```

**2**. в html представленного фрагмента есть поле `input[name=uploaded_image]`. Его нужно расположить внутри основной формы, чтобы при отправке основной формы на сервер уходил id файла или имя или то, чем вы будете идентифицировать файл. При отправке основной формы на сервер, предполагается, что файл уже давно обработан и сохранен (это произошло по адресу, указанному в action), а вместе с формой вы получаете ссылку на него, чтобы привязать готовый файл к материалу.

**2.5**. Вероятно, подправить стили по своему желанию. Особенно превьюшку, я сейчас не проверял, как она выглядит. Нет под рукой серверного обработчика.

При необходимости можно допилить загрузку нескольких файлов (это я уже делал неоднократно с представленным кодом), фильтр выбора файлов по типу файла, удаление загруженных файлов, показ загруженных ранее файлов (в формах редактирования) с возможностью их удаления и многое другое.

---

### Пример

К сожалению, **полноценную демонстрацию организовать не могу**. Нет серверной поддержки. Поэтому сообщение "**Изображение не загружено**" - все, на что можно рассчитывать.

Местные сниппеты не совсем корректно отрабатывают, нет alert и event'a dragenter, поэтому лучше всего смотреть **на jsfiddle**:

**https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/vyhhxvxu/3/**

```js
    $.fn.myLoadImage = function(options){
        if(!options) options = {};
        var default_options = {
            width: false, //ширина превьюшки по-умолчанию, которая будет добавлена в форму. может быть переопределена в ответе сервера
            height: false, //высота превьюшки по-умолчанию, которая будет добавлена в форму. может быть переопределена в ответе сервера
            afterLoad: function(form, data){}, //функция, вызываемая после загрузки 
            setImage: function(data){
              var file = data.thumbnail || data.filepath,
                  thumbWidth = data.width||params.width||'',
                  thumbHeight = data.height||params.height||''.

              //в форму добавляем (или изменяем, если он уже добавлен) элемент img.uploaded_image с превьюшкой
              if(form.find('img.uploaded_image').length){
                  form.find('img.uploaded_image').attr({
                      src:file,
                      width:thumbWidth,
                      height:thumbHeight
                  });
              } else {
                  var image = $('<img class="uploaded_image" src="'+file+'" alt="upload image" width="'+thumbWidth+'" height="'+thumbHeight+'">');
                  form.append(image);
              }

              //после формы в HTML идет скрытый инпут, куда добавляем имя загруженного файла
              $('input[name="uploaded_image"]').val(data.id);

              //вызываем функцию afterLoad, которую можно определить в параметрах
              if(params.afterLoad) params.afterLoad(form, data);
            }
        };
        var params = $.extend(true, {}, default_options, options),
            form = $(this);

        form.on('change','input[type=file]',function(){

            var iframe = $("<iframe id='upload_image_iframe' name='upload_image_iframe' style='display: none;'></iframe>"),
                input = $(this);

            iframe.appendTo($("body")).on('load',function () {
                var response = $(this).contents().find("body").text();

                try {
                    var data = JSON.parse(response);
                    if (data.error)
                    {
                        alert(data.error.replace("\\r\\n","\r\n","g"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        params.setImage(data);
                    }
                }
                catch(e) {
                    alert('Изображение не загружено');
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    iframe.remove();
                },1000);

                input.val(null);

                return false;
            });

            form.attr('target', 'upload_image_iframe').submit();
        }).on('dragenter', function(){
            $(this).addClass('dragenter');
        }).on('dragleave', function(){
            $(this).removeClass('dragenter');
        });
    };

    $('#imageForm').myLoadImage();
```

```css
.image-form{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;    
}
.image-form input[type=file]{
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0;
}
.image-form .uploaded_image{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
.image-form:hover .mask{
  background-color: #F5FFF8;

}
.image-form:hover .mask .mask-inner{
  border: 3px dotted #5eb666;  
}
.image-form.error .mask{
  background-color: #FFF5F6;  
}
.image-form.error .mask .mask-inner{
  border: 3px dotted #FF7177;
}
.image-form .mask {
  background-color: #F5F8FF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #ccc inset;  
}
.image-form .mask .mask-inner {
  width: 84%;
  height: 88%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 8%;
  border: 3px dotted #71B5FF;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.image-form.dragenter{
  background-color: #f9fff9;
  border-color: #008700;
}
.image-form.dragenter .mask{
  background-color: #F5FFF8;
}
.image-form.dragenter .mask .mask-inner{
  border-color: #5eb666;
  color: #5eb666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photo-box">
  <form id="imageForm" class="image-form" action="/image/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload_image">
    <input type="submit" style="display:none">
    <div class="mask">
      <div class="mask-inner">

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <input type="hidden" name="uploaded_image" value="" />
</div>
```