# Множественная загрузка файлов через drag and drop при отправке формы. Без аякса

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, drag-n-drop

Суть вопроса:

Имеется форма подачи объяления. Необходимо загрузить фотографии через драг энд дроп. Но сделать это нужно при отправке всех полей формы, т.е. за раз. Фотографии должны загружатся без аякса, т.к. обявления на сервере на момент загрузки иображений еще нет. Есть ли возможность реализовать такой функционал?
Браузер запрещает джаваскриптом изменять отправляемые файлы.

Comment: Может, всё-таки ajax'ом? По отправке формы можете делать единственный ajax-запрос со всеми данными, а после получения ответа уже перебрасывать на новую страницу.

Comment: если бы можно было аяксом, не писал бы сюда) browser file api может помочь как думаете?

Comment: то есть вам нужно сделать это совсем без js?

Comment: `drop` можно только слушать JavaScript'ом, соотв. далее только JS'ом его обрабатывать. Вот тут кто-то сделал [грязный хак](http://fiddle.jshell.net/BADfT/12/): над дропзоной начинает под мышку подсовывать обычный file input : ) Остроумно, но я бы не стал так делать на продакшн.

Comment: Повторю предложение с ajax'ом: юзер заполняет форму, и выбирает файлы. Жмёт единственную кнопку "Отправить". Но она отлавливается JS'ом, который отправляет ajax'ом данные формы и файлы. А получив отбивку с id сохранённого объявления, перекидывает юзера уже на след. страницу. Внешне выглядит как обычное сохранение через кнопку и POST.

Comment: @Sergiks согласен, для большого портала это перебор. Я и сам обдумывал предложенный вами вариант, но оставлял его на крайний случай, но идей больше нет)

Comment: Возможно такое решение вам понравится http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627350/17974

Answer (score 1):

Решение вашей задачи:

Статья

https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/

Демо

https://css-tricks.com/examples/DragAndDropFileUploading/

Для вас подойдет режим **Submit On Demand**

Вся необходимая и пошаговая инструкция присутствует в статье, можно дополнительно передавать кастомные данные и отправлять форму обычным `post multipart/form-data` запросом.